# Concatenate all pyspark dataframe columns into one string column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, concatenation

I have the following pyspark dataframe

| identification | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to concatenate all columns from p1 to p4 in a way to gather the values of 1 and 0 in this way

| identification | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | joined_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1001 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0110 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0001 |

All columns from p1 to p4 are Integer, so I tried to cast them into string before concatenate all columns ( except the 'identification' column ) in this way:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_concat=df.withColumn('joined_column', F.concat([F.col(c).cast(StringType()) for c in df.columns if  c!='identification']))
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
```

Is there any solution or other way to concatenate all columns of a pyspark dataframe into one string ?

Comment: unpack the list -- `concat(*[col(c) ... ])` -- as concat accepts columns only

Comment: Thaanks @samkart it works, I did not pay attention to this small detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the question based on @samkart comment. We don't need to convert each column into a string, it will be converted automatically while concatenating.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_concat=df.withColumn('joined_column', F.concat(*[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if  c!='identification']))
```

This will be true independent of columns number and names

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `concat_ws`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
df = df.withColumn('joined_column',concat_ws('',df.p1, df.p2, df.p3, df.p4))
```

Comment: This code alone will not solve the problem. You need to convert p1 to p4 as int type and post that your code will concat the data

Comment: Works for me !! Can you please test before commenting? :)

Comment: I tested in Databricks.. It's coming like 1.00.00.01.0

Comment: I think OP has asked for (py)spark and not Databricks. And clearly the values are integers as the it is shown as `1` and **not** `1.0`

Comment: I am using pyspark code. Databricks as the interface. For me when I uploaded the csv file having Integer data, it's getting converted as double . May be because of that, your code didn't work. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code. If you will check your schema, the data in those columns may not be integer. You need to convert p1 to p4 as integer type

```
  from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
  
df = df \
  .withColumn("p1" , df["p1"].cast(IntegerType()))   \
  .withColumn("p2", df["p2"].cast(IntegerType()))    \
  .withColumn("p3"  ,df["p3"].cast(IntegerType())) \
  .withColumn("p4"  ,   df["p4"]  .cast(IntegerType())) 

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
df = df.withColumn('joined_column',sf.concat(sf.col('p1'),sf.col('p2'),sf.col('p3'),sf.col('p4')))

display(df)
```